# How do I insert comma or replace space with comma in string variable?

Tags: powershell

Hi when I run the command: `Get-XASession -Full -ServerName myserver01 | select SessionId,SessionName,AccountName,ServerName,LogOnTime,DisconnectTime,State,ConnectTime,BrowserNam | ft -auto`

I get among other things other things ConnectTime in this format: 
9/1/2014 3:56:17 AM

When I export this into to a csv and import it to Excel I need to do some manual steps to separate columns like this. Is there an easy easy to replace space in this variable(?) with a comma?

Or if there is any xenapp powershell gurus who see this there might even be a command that gives you the date/time in a better format.

//Fredrik
Thanks

Comment: How do you do the CSV export? It should enclose the timestamp in double quotes `"`, so the answer lies within fixing that step.

Comment: Have you tried adding: `| ConvertTo-Csv`

Comment: I use the command "Export-Csv" when I export, a built in command from Citrix SDK. I seam that every selected item is treated as a string.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is something you can use:

```
$Date = Get-Date
$ModifiedDate = $Date -replace(" ",",")
Write-Host "ModifiedDate contains: $ModifiedDate"
```

You can also export with another `Delimiter` like a semicolon:

```
$Stuff | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Test.csv' -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Get-XASession -Full -ServerName myserver01 | select SessionId,SessionName,AccountName,ServerName,LogOnTime,DisconnectTime,State,@{n='ConnectTime';e={$_.connectTime -replace ' ',','}},BrowserNam
```